# salesforce: how easier apex and visual force to learn by having JAVA/j2EE background?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

i am new to salesforce and i would like to know how this APEX programming to learn as compared to java. kindly advise me whether the apex code is too difficult to catch Vs Java.

How many days to finish from scratch total salesforce material , theory  to hands on.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site — this question is a bit too opinon-based for this site and it's easy to find information on this topic. Check out the guides on developer.force.com for more information. If you know Java you'll find Apex very famiiliar, but the harder part is learning about the platforms limits etc. rather than the code.

Answer (score 1):

Apex is like water-downed Java.  If you're fluent in Java, I think you'll have a fairly easy time getting to know Apex + Salesforce.  The hardest step will be getting to know **[Salesforce's `Objects` and `Classes`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_defining.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_defining.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)** and write your code within the **[Governor Limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)**.

For me, it took about 10-12 months of working with Salesforce before I felt very confident with my work, and I don't have a background in Java.  If you really know Java, I could reasonably imagine someone being able to do some damage in ~6-9 months.  It really depends on  a couple of factors:

1. What's the purpose of the work you'll be doing on the Salesforce platform?  If you're new to the platform, it'll take awhile to get use to its *Architecture*: how data is arranged in Standard and Custom Objects, **how to best fit relationships among your data** with your **User Experience**(Grandparent-Parent-Child, many-many relationships, Junction Objects) as well as how you want the whole interface to come together with `Triggers`, `Scheduled Apex`, interaction with `Apex Classes` (including `VF Controllers`)
2. The other **huge** aspect of Salesforce is creating `Visualforce Pages` to  be used internally as `/apex/MyVisualforcePage?myPageParameter=somethingFun` or externally on a `Salesforce Site` as `mySiteName.force.com/MySitePage?anotherPageParameter=tomRobbins`.  Your ability to write awesome VF Pages is directly proportional to your **HTML + CSS + JavaScript (*easily accomplished via* jQuery) skills**.  If you want to customize the User Experience in any way, shape, or form, you're solution will lie somewhere with Visualforce Pages, so you better start dabbling now.  And if you know Java, controllers will  be a breeze; it's the CSS + maybe jQuery that could be the hold up.

Salesforce offer a lot of amazing features with the price of some interesting limitations.  However, I've always found a clever (usually more elagant) solution around these limitations--though at the price of education.